# Modeling or data error causing large standard errors in GLMM (lme4) with repeated measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, glmmadaptive

**The aim:**

I am trying to investigate the difference of COPD incidence in participants in stratified age groups of alcohol consumption debut.

**The dataset:**

I have a dataset of approx 4700 participants who answered a questionnaire and performed a lung function test at both baseline and follow up.
The dataframe `df` is in long format with `patient_id` as identifier and year as cluster variable for identifying baseline `2004` and follow up `2008`.

`COPD` is the outcome measure and a factor with 2 levels (yes or no), which is determined by a lung function test. It was tested at both baseline and follow up and it was defined at baseline as post-bronchodilatory FEV1/FVC ratio < 0.7 and at follow up as the same *OR if they were diagnosed with COPD at baseline*. This way all baseline-COPD participants who were lost to follow up were assigned to COPD at follow up time as well - as COPD is assumed to be chronic. Default were set to `No COPD` so everyone else were assumed to be without disease.

`AgeAlcoholDebut` is the grouping variable. A factor stating at what age they started to drink alcohol according to which age group participants self-reported to belong at debut.

**The models:**

I'm trying to construct GLMMs using the `glmer()` function from `lme4`-package to account for repeated measures.

I am trying to make both an unadjusted model and an adjusted model. Both will be presented below - but for now i'm just providing the data for the unadjusted model. Tell me if you'd like the data for the adjusted model as well.

The unadjusted model, i believe, is quite simple. Yet **the output is with large estimates and large standard errors (see below).**

The adjusted model is the same and also i'm getting some warnings regarding unable to evaluate scaled gradient, failing to converge: degenerate Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues - i am aware that the warnings might be due to the model being too complex, but here i am hoping fixing the underlying issue with the unadjusted model might help my adjusted model. Regarding the warnings i have tried rescaling and different optimizers using Ben Bolkers guide at https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html .

Also i might add when doing a GEE using the geepack. I get more reliable results which do not have as wide 95CI. The reasoning as to why im not just going with the GEE is that 1) to my understanding GLMM is better at dealing with some missingness (whereas GEE is just forced to omit the rows) and 2) I'm later doing a model with a continuous outcome variable (FEV1) which isn't possible with GEE (as far as i know) and i would for simplicity like it to be done with the same statistical method.

**The problem and my questions:**

The main problem is that i get these really large og really small intercept estimates (like log(odds) -28.2487) and large standard errors (like 3.1867).

- Do you agree that these results do not seem valid and they're most likely a result of wrongful modelling or mistake in how the data is set up?
- Is the modelling correctly set up? For example: `COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + year + (1 | patient_id)`
- If so, can you help me figure out where the mistake in the data is?

***What i've done, reproducible example and outputs :***

Packages used:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(optimx)
```

Dataframe for the unadjusted model:

https://pastebin.com/YsjHJXia

Output from `dput()` was too long to be included in the text. And sorry it's so long, I tried to shorten it but then the models came with new warnings (like with the adjusted example below) which i suspected would be drawing attention from the real problem.

**The unadjusted model:**

Creating an unadjusted GLMM model with lme4 package modeling COPD explained by Age of Alcohol Debut (with never drinkers as ref.) incorporating the repeated measures with year as a fixed effects and patient_id as cluster variable

```
unadj_glme <- glmer(COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + year + (1|patient_id), 
                   data = unadj_df, family = binomial(link = "logit"), glmerControl(optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb'))) 

summary(unadj_glme)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + year + (1 | patient_id)
   Data: unadj_df
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb"))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2170.4   2233.8  -1076.2   2152.4     8469 

Scaled residuals: 
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.016660 -0.000927 -0.000001 -0.000001  0.066825 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 patient_id (Intercept) 7610     87.23   
Number of obs: 8478, groups:  patient_id, 4239

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    -28.2487     1.6444 -17.179   <2e-16 ***
AgeAlcoholDebutlessthan14years   0.1259     3.1867   0.040    0.968    
AgeAlcoholDebut14to16years      -0.1713     1.6747  -0.102    0.919    
AgeAlcoholDebut17to18years       0.2490     1.5409   0.162    0.872    
AgeAlcoholDebut19to20years       0.2771     1.6341   0.170    0.865    
AgeAlcoholDebut21to25years       0.2980     1.7457   0.171    0.864    
AgeAlcoholDebutmorethan25years   0.1833     1.6653   0.110    0.912    
year2008                        14.0386     0.5777  24.302   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) AgAD14 AAD141 AAD171 AAD192 AAD212 AgAD25
AgAlchlDb14 -0.409                                          
AgAlchD1416 -0.776  0.399                                   
AgAlchD1718 -0.842  0.434  0.823                            
AgAlchD1920 -0.793  0.409  0.776  0.844                     
AgAlchD2125 -0.743  0.383  0.727  0.790  0.746              
AgAlchlDb25 -0.781  0.402  0.762  0.829  0.782  0.732       
year2008    -0.451  0.006  0.011  0.009  0.006  0.005  0.009
```

My thoughts the output is:

- Intercept estimate is -28.25 and large standard errors.
- Resulting in when exponentiated and recalculated to confidence intervals are enormously wide. For example <14 years old group is having a 95% CI as 0.00 to 585 and 14-16 years old group have 95CI 0.03-22.4. (I just used tbl_regression() to exponentiate).
- Also estimate of year 2008 is 14.03 and when exponentiated results in OR 1,249,953.
- I suspect something is off with either my modeling or how the data is coded

**The adjusted model:**

Creating an adjusted GLMM model (same as above) but with more adjusting variables

```
adj_glme_scaled <- glmer(COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + Age + Sex + SmokingStatus + PackYears + ConfirmedAsthma + PrimarySecondarySchool + HigherEducation + year + (1|patient_id), 
                   data = adj_df_scaled, family = binomial(link = "logit"), control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                            optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(adj_glme_scaled)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + Age + Sex + SmokingStatus + PackYears +  
    ConfirmedAsthma + PrimarySecondarySchool + HigherEducation +      year + (1 | patient_id)
   Data: scaled_long_df_agegroups_COPD2_adj
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1947.2   2081.3   -953.6   1907.2     6031 

Scaled residuals: 
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.066615 -0.001145 -0.000013 -0.000005  0.140706 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 patient_id (Intercept) 1832     42.8    
Number of obs: 6051, groups:  patient_id, 3786

Fixed effects:
                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           -23.48527   10.86586  -2.161   0.0307 *  
AgeAlcoholDebutlessthan14years         -9.16272   19.12084  -0.479   0.6318    
AgeAlcoholDebut14to16years             -0.55530   10.79921  -0.051   0.9590    
AgeAlcoholDebut17to18years             -0.37785   10.03797  -0.038   0.9700    
AgeAlcoholDebut19to20years             -0.34655   10.46873  -0.033   0.9736    
AgeAlcoholDebut21to25years             -0.19921   11.17023  -0.018   0.9858    
AgeAlcoholDebutmorethan25years          0.03002   10.55937   0.003   0.9977    
Age                                     0.66298    2.52737   0.262   0.7931    
SexMale                                 0.30430    5.41271   0.056   0.9552    
SmokingStatusFormer                     0.92559    6.51731   0.142   0.8871    
SmokingStatusCurrent                    2.02088    6.71264   0.301   0.7634    
PackYears                               0.42735    1.70200   0.251   0.8017    
ConfirmedAsthmaAsthma                   2.49650    4.30939   0.579   0.5624    
PrimarySecondarySchool8to10years       -0.49171    4.80998  -0.102   0.9186    
PrimarySecondarySchoolmorethan10years  -0.85873    6.63901  -0.129   0.8971    
HigherEducationlessthan3years          -0.18785    5.54385  -0.034   0.9730    
HigherEducation3to4years               -0.14614    5.19366  -0.028   0.9776    
HigherEducationmorethan4years          -0.33717    6.50622  -0.052   0.9587    
year2008                               10.64035    2.38785   4.456 8.35e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 19 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK)
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues

Advarsel: variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RXAdvarsel: variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RXAdvarsel: variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

As i've stated above: i am aware the model might be too complex.

Comment: When I see standard errors that high, the first thing I think is that your predictors are highly collinear. This could be due to a coding error in the creation of the AgeAlcohol... dummy variables or could just be a feature of your data. Check out the perturb package: https://github.com/JohnHendrickx/Perturb

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit more of a comment than an answer at this stage...

I certainly agree that something seems off here. Obviously you have had problems with convergence. In similar situations I have had reasonable success using the package `GLMMadaptive`, the author of which we are lucky to have as a regular contributor here. I will add the `GLMMadaptive` tab to the question after I post this, so hopefully Dimitris will see the thread and hopefully be able to offer some help.

Anyway, the point is that `GLMMadaptive` handles the integration over the random effects using the adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule for approximating the integrals, whereas (I think) `lme4` uses the less accurate Laplace approximation. So, I was able to fit the "unadjusted" model with `GLMMadaptive` and got the following results:

```
library(GLMMadaptive)
dt <- read.csv("634993.csv")
dt$COPD <- as.factor(dt$COPD)
dt$AgeAlcoholDebut <- as.factor(dt$AgeAlcoholDebut)

m0 <- mixed_model(
  fixed = COPD ~ AgeAlcoholDebut + year,
  random = ~ 1 | patient_id, 
  data = dt, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit"),
  iter_EM = 0, optimizer = "nlminb", iter_qN_incr = 5
)
```

producing:

```
Random effects covariance matrix:
              StdDev
(Intercept) 11.46721

Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std.Err z-value p-value
(Intercept)                    -754.5274     NaN     NaN      NA
AgeAlcoholDebut17to18years        0.4648  0.2765  1.6810 0.09277
AgeAlcoholDebut19to20years        0.5046  0.3250  1.5526 0.12051
AgeAlcoholDebut21to25years        0.5401  0.3788  1.4256 0.15398
AgeAlcoholDebutlessthan14years    0.3020  0.8912  0.3389 0.73472
AgeAlcoholDebutmorethan25years    0.3932  0.3370  1.1667 0.24333
AgeAlcoholDebutNever              0.2700  0.4845  0.5573 0.57735
year                              0.3694     NaN     NaN      NA

Integration:
method: adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule
quadrature points: 11

Optimization:
method: quasi-Newton
converged: TRUE 
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(var_betas)) : NaNs produced
```

So, there is obviously still a problem with the estimation of the intercept and `year`, but the standard errors for the contrasts for `AgeAlcoholDebut` seem much better.

I also decided to fit a model without random effects:

```
m0_glm_null <- glm(COPD ~ 1, data = dt, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(m0_glm_null)
```

and obtained this:

```
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    -128.14084   33.10281  -3.871 0.000108 ***
AgeAlcoholDebut17to18years        0.43497    0.10284   4.230 2.34e-05 ***
AgeAlcoholDebut19to20years        0.47498    0.11798   4.026 5.67e-05 ***
AgeAlcoholDebut21to25years        0.51835    0.13437   3.858 0.000114 ***
AgeAlcoholDebutlessthan14years    0.26539    0.31945   0.831 0.406110    
AgeAlcoholDebutmorethan25years    0.37129    0.12268   3.026 0.002475 ** 
AgeAlcoholDebutNever              0.29661    0.17315   1.713 0.086713 .  
year                              0.06273    0.01650   3.802 0.000144 ***
```

I don't have time to investigate this further at the moment (another reason why this is really a comment not an answer), but hopefully it will give you some other avenues to pursue.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, Robert. I will look into the `GLMMadaptive` package and also i'll cross my fingers Dimitris will give his 2 cents. Do you have any ideas what might be the cause of the problems with estimation of intercept and cluster variable? I see even in the glm without random effects theres problems with atleast the intercept. Also i'm curious, could the non-random effects model potentially be valid as i only have 2 time points in the repeated measures?